# Reuse a function repetitively in PHP

Tags: php, function, reusability

I have this code for encrypting the ID of every row:

```
class publicfunction {
  public static function EncryptString($input) {
    $Key = "KEY_GOES_HERE";
    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
  }
}

// I skipped the code for read the mysql
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
  $ProductID = $fetch[0];

  print "<a href='mstpublc.php?id=" . publicfunction::EncryptString($ProductID) . "'>Edit&nbsp;</a>";
}
```

There are more than 1 data on the `$fetch` but it only return 1 row. What's wrong with the code? But when I omit the EncryptString function on the `while` section, it returns all the value on the `$fetch`. FYI, while in localhost, it works well, but when I uploaded the code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps your live server doesn't have mcrypt installed?

Comment: I suspect you have register globals turned off, you should change, `$ProductID` to `$fetch['ProductID']`...

Comment: @Jack: Oic, yes it perhaps. How to get it installed on the server?

Comment: Inspect your server logs for errors. Looks like @Jacks's right.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake while writing the thread. I've edited the code above..

Comment: well thats not good lol, `$ProductID = $fetch[0];
` is also wrong, it will overwrite with the same value

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I fail to see the problem with that?

Comment: @webbandit : if you have access to logs, read them (refresh your page and write tail /var/log/apache2/error.log )
You can also have a look inside your phpinfo() output

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: No.. While I omitted the Encrypt function, then it read all of the rows..

Comment: I think the problem is as mentioned by @Jack. You should check the php.ini file on your server, and check if extension for php_mcrypt is commented. If so, uncomment it.

Comment: @Jack: Well, I've checked it and it doesn't has any mcrypt installed on the server. How to do that? It's use LAMP...

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 installing mcrypt can be done in a number of ways, using package manager is probably the easiest (e.g. yum, emerge, etc.)

Comment: @artragi - it's not my question, man )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the mcrypt on the live server. Thanks all :)